# Does the Router running multi routing protocol progresses received the routes will store into the Forwarding table?

Tags: router, igp, route

I have a question about the Router running multi routing protocol progresses.
if the bellow snapshot R1 have EIGRP and OSPF progresses, if the EIGRP progress received the routes from R3, will it store to its forwarding table directly? and received the R2's given routes of OSPF will store into its forwarding table too? so in the router Forwarding table, the forwarding table will save both type routes right?

[image]

---

**EDIT-01**

my questions are:

1. if the EIGRP progress received the routes from R3, will it store to its FIB directly?
2. in the R1's FIB will store two types routes completely, one type is EIGRP, the other is OSPF?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Routing protocols have a priority value called Administrative Distance(AD). If two routing protocol processes with different AD values send the same route to RIB, the one with the lowest AD will be selected and installed. 
In your case you have: OSPF (110) , EIGRP(90) and external (redistributed) EIGRP(170).
So, the EIGRP routes learned directly from an EIGRP neighbor will be installed, as well as the OSPF routes. The redistributed EIGRP routes won't be installed because their AD is higher than OSPF's AD.
AD values can be manipulated in order to effect which protocol's routes will be selected by RIB.

Comment: Every routing protocol progress have its only RIB.

Comment: Yes, and there is the main RIB - which is the routing table

Comment: Also need to know that only routes that are installed in FIB will be redistributed into another routing process.

Comment: @sergeyrar You did not mention the FIB.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38588/rib-vs-fib-differences